# XML schema pattern, range of signs

Tags: xml, xsd

How to define an xsd pattern, where you have a range of amount of signs? Let's say i want 1 upper-case letter and between 1 to 20 lower-case letters.
I came up with something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="NameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z][a-z]{1-20}"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: @zx485 that comment should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `,` instead of a `-` to specify the range:

```
<xsd:pattern value="[A-Z][a-z]{1,20}"/>.
```

Then your code will work as expected.